# PHP var in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to use a php variable in my javascript code, but i cant seem to get it working. Here is my js and php code:

```
<?php $s = "woo"; ?>
var images = <?=$s?>;
```

What i want to achieve, is a php variable in javascript ENCLOSED with ['']; With other words, so that the javascript code reads it like this: ['woo'];
I could really need some help, as i am very new to javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this: `var images = <?$s?>;` work?

Comment: create a quote inside your javascript. Please use standard and a readable php coding.

Comment: @jsve its wrong, use `var images = "<?php echo $s; ?>";`

Comment: var images = '<?php echo $s ?>';

Comment: You should be able to do `var images = "<?=$s?>";`

Comment: The thread was edited.

Comment: Remember that you can "view source" on the page to see the exact JavaScript that's being rendered by the PHP.

Comment: The problem is in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `json_encode` for all values "passed" to JavaScript - this will prevent against injection, accidental or otherwise. It also trivially handles quotes and allows complex object graphs to be supplied. If not already, I imagine that images is really, or should be, an *array* ..

```
var images = <?= json_encode($s) ?>;
```

Or

```
var images = <?php echo json_encode($s); php?>;
```

Look at the *actual HTML* to see what is being emitted, and that it is valid - the original yields JavaScript akin to `var images = woo;`, which will result in a ReferenceError (on woo).

Answer (score 0):

One trick you can use is this, when you are inside a .js file it can be helpful, because php doesnt work.

Put the value of your php value inside a div as content, and then grab that in the javascript.

in the php file:

```
<div id="sVar" style="display:none;"><?php echo $s; ?></div>
```

in js:

```
var images = document.getElementById('sVar').innerHTML;
```

Comment: This did not work, weirdly enough.

Comment: Does your php file load before the javascript runs, if not it wont have a div of that id to grab.